# Put on a very impressive display

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice, synonyms

I found this phrase in a translation studies textbook,

> Veeraphol Nakonluang-Promotion put on a very impressive display to knock out defending champion Joichiro Tatsuyoshi of Japan to become the new World Boxing Council (WBC) bantamweight champion in Japan yesterday.

I know the meaning of the phrase.

But I wonder...
Is this a fixed phrase?
Are there any good (perhaps better) alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is a fixed phrase or a commonly used expression.

*Impressive/Fine show of skill* could be used alternatively.